# Yii: Limit checkbox selection under cCheckboxColumn in cgridview according to a dynamic number

Tags: php, javascript, yii

I have a cgridview with a ccheckboxcolumn that allow checkbox selection. 
However, I want to limit the number of checkbox that a person can select based on a dynamic value.

I've researched a bit and this is what I've done. But it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

My codes are as below:

**cgridview ccheckboxcolumn:**

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'v-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
        'summaryText'=>'',//remove display result count
        'columns'=>array(

            array(
                'id'=>'autoId',
                'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
                'header'=>'',
                'selectableRows'=>'null', 
                'cssClassExpression'=>'$data->status=="accepted" ? "hidden" : ""', 
            ),
        ),
));
```

**Ajax submit button of cActiveForm:**

```
echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Submit',CHtml::normalizeUrl(array('default/viewV','render'=>false)),array('success'=>'js: function(data) {
        $("#view").dialog("open");
    }'),array('id'=>'submitButton'));
```

**Javascript that limits the checkbox selection:**

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('restrictCbSelection','$("#submitButton").click(function() {


var checkboxCount=$("#v-grid").yiiGridView("getChecked","autoId");

if(checkboxCount.length>6) //will be changing 5 to a variable and that variable value will change dynamically
 {
     alert("Pls select only 6 items or less");
     return false;
 }

else console.log(checkboxCount);

});');
```

Answer (score 1):

yii framework don't provide the way that control that you need, but you can control with some javascript on grid.

Test this way:

1. Disable the select-all rows, in yii 1.10 you need do this with javascript, but in yii 1.11 you can use the headerTemplate in CCheckBoxColumn class
2. Control the ajax update, similiar to step 1, if use yii 1.11, avoid this step
3. Control the selectionChange, a lot of javascript...

### Step 1

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('restrictCbSelection','
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("disabled", true).attr("keys", "");
});');
```

### Step 2

On CGridView

```
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id){
        $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("disabled", true).attr("keys", "");
    }',
```

### Step 3

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id'=>'pais-grid',
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'selectableRows'=>2, //<-- this means multiselect
    'afterAjaxUpdate'=>'js:function(id){
        $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("disabled", true).attr("keys", "");
    }',
'selectionChanged'=>'js:function(id){
    var keys = $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("keys");
    var sels = $("#" + id).yiiGridView("getSelection")
    var ext = $(sels).not(keys.split(","))
    if( $("#"+id+" :checked").size() <= 3 )  //<-- this is your variable number, you can use javascript value
        $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("keys", sels.join(","));
    else
        $("#pais-grid .select-on-check[value="+ext[0]+"]").click().prop("checked",false);
    //your code here, if you need more.
}',
'columns'=>array(
    array(
        'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',
        'selectableRows'=>null, 
    ),
    'id',
    'nombre',
    'codigo',
),
));
```

this work for me... very well, tested on google chrome
excuseme my english, my native language is spanish

Comment: I'm using yii version 1.1.10. I tried using your method but it can't work and I'm still figuring out why. Will it affect the codes if my cgridview is render into a cjuidialog instead of a normal page? And what does " $("#pais-grid .select-on-check[value="+ext[0]+"]").click().prop("checked",false);" and "$("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("keys", sels.join(","));" means?

Comment: this `var sels =  $("#" + id).yiiGridView("getSelection")` get all selected id-rows, this `var keys = $("#pais-grid .select-on-check-all").attr("keys");` get all id-rows selected before this click-event. well with this `var ext = $(sels).not(keys.split(","))` you can get all id-rows that not selected before, then when you get the limit (in this case 3 ) you need to unselected ( why unselect, because the cgridwiev always select). how unselect, here the code: `$("#pais-grid .select-on-check[value="+ext[0]+"]").click().prop("checked",false);`